# PHP: Passing resource datatype as a parameter to function

Tags: php, file

Lets say we have a file named languages.txt which has the following content:

> AJAX HTML CSS JQUERY

Here's the php code to read the above file:

```
<?php

function read ( $fh2, $length ) {

    return ( fread($fh2,$length) );

}

$fh1 = fopen ( 'languages.txt', 'r' ) ;

echo read ( $fh1, 7 ) ;

echo read ( $fh1, 4 ) ;

?>
```

We know that in PHP local variables are local to functions and global variables are available outside of functions.

So, considering $fh1 as a global variable, $fh2 as a local variable and both being independent of each other I expected the output to be

> AJAX HTAJAX

But, the output comes out to be

> AJAX HTML C

Can anyone explain me what's happening? When a `resource` datatype is passed to a function as parameter, is it passed by reference unlike `int` datatype?

Comment: It has nothing with local/global variables

Comment: A resource var is a reference to an external resource, so whether it is the original resource var or a copy it is still a reference to the external resource, in this case a handle to an open file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using functions like `fread()` the file pointer moves forward in your file. This is why your input is not what you expect it to be.

If you want to return to the beginning of the file, you can use `rewind()`.

What you could do is `$line = fgets($fh)` and get a whole line, then depending on the separator used you can split said line into an array like so `$exploded = explode("\t", $line)`.

Comment: `$fh` is the file descriptor, my bad.

Comment: @JulienLachal

So, does it mean while there might be many variables acting as handles to a file, there can only be one file pointer (Unless a new fopen() is initiated)?

Comment: $fh is the resource with which you access your file, but there is an invisible pointer when you use functions to navigate the file (`fread(), fgets(), fgetcsv()`) ... If you want to move said pointer, you have functions like `fseek(), rewind()`. Take a look at [this](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2002/12/12/php_foundations.html)

Answer (score 0):

The resource returned by [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) does not contain the content of the file. It encapsulates a file handle provided by the OS.

A file handle is used by the OS to identify a data structure that contains the information about the status of the open file. This status information includes a so-called file pointer that is the position inside the file where the next read or write operation will take place.

Your code passes the value returned by `fopen()` by value but, because it is just a pointer to the actual data structure, no matter how many (local or global) copies of `$fh1` you create, they all point to the same structure that manages the same file in the background.

This means the following code:

```
$fh1 = fopen('languages.txt', 'r');
echo(read($fh1, 7));             // 'AJAX HT'
$fh2 = fh1;
echo(read($fh2, 4));             // 'ML C'
echo(read($fh1, 3));             // 'SS '
$fh3 = $fh2;
echo(read($fh3, 6));             // 'JQUERY'
```

will output the content of the file, even if three variables are used to read the content.